# jasypt with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets, jasypt

I want to use Jasypt with Hibernate in servlets. I refered [Jasypt here](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html). It says how to configure Hibernate. But, still it is not clear that how I can handle `session` to save & retrieve results. I did configurations of Hibernate as mentioned in above link(and I m not going to past them here again). Let me know how to save & retrieve data with Session.
For a simple example,lets say, I have a table called 'login' consisting 2 columns 'name','password'. column 'name' data type is varchar and 'password' is varbinary. The `pojo` class has variables String name and byte[] password.   How can I save and retrieve data from table 'login'.At least any useful link which explain with sample codes ll be appreciated.

**Edit**
When I configured hibernate .hbm file & try to save as usual, an exception is also thrown.

Comment: This link may help you. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2391734

Comment: Thanx Hardik. But it doesn't clearly show what I need.